# check marking all the checkbox using jquery on click of a button

Tags: jquery

This is how my table structure looks,

```
 <table>
    <tbody>   
    <tr>
    <td id="**SelectCheckBox**" class="helpBod">
    <input id="TimeSheetWebUserControl1_TimeSheetRepeater_ctl01_CheckBox0" type="checkbox"  name="TimeSheetWebUserControl1$TimeSheetRepeater$ctl01$CheckBox0"/>
    </td>
    <td>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td id="**SelectCheckBox**" class="helpBod">
    <input id="TimeSheetWebUserControl1_TimeSheetRepeater_ctl02_CheckBox1" type="checkbox"  name="TimeSheetWebUserControl1$TimeSheetRepeater$ctl02$CheckBox1"/>
    </td>
   <td>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I have a button SelectAll im going to call a jquery function to check mark all the checkbox

function look this

```
function jqCheckAll() {
        $("td#" + 'SelectCheckBox' + 'input:checkbox').attr('checked', true);

      }
```

problem is this will check mark only only checkbox what if i have 100 checkbox, i want to check mark all the this 100 checkbox on click of select all button.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@sameer, what you want to do is add a class to all the checkboxes you want checked.
Here I added a class "checkall" to the checkboxes that will be checked.

```
<input type="button" name="checkit" id="checkit" value="Check All">

 <table>
    <tbody>   
    <tr>
    <td>
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkall" name="TimeSheetWebUserControl1$TimeSheetRepeater$ctl01$CheckBox0" id="TimeSheetWebUserControl1_TimeSheetRepeater_ctl01_CheckBox0" />
    </td>
    <td>
    <input type="checkbox" name="chk1" id="chk1" />
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkall" name="TimeSheetWebUserControl1$TimeSheetRepeater$ctl02$CheckBox1" id="TimeSheetWebUserControl1_TimeSheetRepeater_ctl02_CheckBox1" />
    </td>
    <td>
   <input type="checkbox" name="chk2" id="chk2" />
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The jQuery is then simple.

```
$('#checkit').click(function() {
    $('input:checkbox.checkall').attr('checked','checked');
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 4):

First, I can't really tell what you mean by "**SelectCheckBox**"; you cannot give all your checkboxes the same "id" value.

To check all the checkboxes in all the "helpBod" td elements, just do this:

```
$('td.helpBod input:checkbox').attr('checked', true);
```

Comment: giving the same name or id will result in array in DOM right.

Comment: Well yes, but you definitely should not do that. It will confuse libraries like jQuery.  The "id" is supposed to be the *identifier*, and it does not make sense for two different things to have the same identifier. Use a "class" value if you need multiple elements to be similar.

Answer (score 4):

```
function jqCheckAll() {
    $("input:checkbox").attr('checked','checked');
}
```

**Update, only checking in a single column:**

Assuming your `select_all` button is inside the same `td` as the checkboxes, just do this:

```
$('td.helpBod .select_all').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('td.helpBod').find(':checkbox').attr('checked', 'checked');
});
```

Again, that assumes your HTML looks something like this (the `select_all` doesn't have to be a button):

```
<td class="helpBod" ... >
  <button class="select_all">Select All</button>
  <input type="checkbox" ... />
  <input type="checkbox" ... />
  <input type="checkbox" ... />
  <input type="checkbox" ... />
</td>
```

Comment: thanks for details,

but if i add one more check box in other column even that will be checked.i want only column of interest to be checked.

Comment: Thanks doug for ur inputs appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what youre asking the easiest way to do that would be

```
$('.helpBod input:checkbox').attr('checked','checked');
```

This only checks the ones you have that class on, so you wont affect other checkboxes you might have elsewhere.